# How to stream audio from AngularJS to Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-speech

I am new to the HTML5 Web Audio API and to Google Cloud Speech API. I am trying to build speech-recognition into an AngularJS application so the user can perform a search using speech-to-text instead of typing into a search with the keyboard.

The intent is to use getUserMedia() to capture and stream audio from the client to the Google [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/), and asynchronously recieve back results.

Google offers a set of [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) that allow you to stream from server-side platforms like C#, Node and Java to their API but I can't find an example showing how I can do either of the following:

- Stream audio from AngularJS directly to Google Cloud Speech API
- Stream audio from AngularJS to a custom API that relays the feed to Google Cloud Speech API using a client library

Has anyone found a way to stream audio from an AngularJS/HTML5 client to an API like the Google Cloud Speech API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

1. Stream client-side [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/web-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/explore-api):

   ```
   function sendBytesToSpeech (bytes, encoding, rate, callback) {
     gapi.client.speech.speech.syncrecognize({
       config: {
         encoding: encoding,
         sampleRate: rate
       },
       audio: {
         content: bytes
       }
     }).execute(function (r) {
       callback(r);
     });
   }

   function sendBlobToSpeech (blob, encoding, rate) {
     var speechSender = new FileReader();
     speechSender.addEventListener('loadend', function () {
       sendBytesToSpeech(btoa(speechSender.result), encoding, rate, uiCallback);
     });
     speechSender.readAsBinaryString(blob);
   }
   ```
2. Stream server-side using [Express and a WebSocket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505524/nodejs-convert-int16array-binary-buffer-to-linear16-encoded-raw-stream-for-googl) or similar configuration in your preferred language.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Strange that the Cloud Speech developer web site (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries) doesn't mention the Javascript client library

Comment: The JavaScript client library is older than the Cloud Client libraries, which are preferred for these APIs - there is not a JavaScript Cloud Client library.

Comment: What I really needed was a client-side integration with the Natural Language API. That said, your references were helpful and did answer my question. Thanks class.

Comment: @vt_todd : Are you able to figure this out?

Comment: Nope - changed jobs and tech stacks, never came back to it sorry.